# send parametres as values using JSON syntax

Tags: javascript, json, syntax-error

i want to send an url with parametres, those parametres are values taken by a form with javascript and i want to use JSON to do it, but when i debug i see this error : Uncaught ReferenceError: name is not defined..

```
function recup()
{
var selectElmt = document.getElementById("name");
var selectcat = document.getElementById("msg");

var name = selectElmt.options[selectElmt.selectedIndex].value;
var msg  = selectcat.options[selectcat.selectedIndex].value;

}


    function go() {      // button send who call the function go

      var p_url="http://mysite.com/class?name=" + name + "&message=" + msg +  
                $.getJSON(p_url, {

            }).done(function( data ) {

                $.each(data, function (key, field) {
                   alert(field);
                });
            });  
                return false;
    }
```

it's a syntax error when calling the value name and msg but i don"t know how to fix it or in the go function

Comment: A `ReferenceError` is not a syntax error, its a runtime error. It means that the variable you are trying to access does not exist in the current scope. It also means that your code is syntactically correct, otherwise it could not run at all. Now, you have `var name  = "test";` at the beginning or your snippet, but there is also a dangling `}`, which somehow suggests that the variables are not defined where `go` can see them. The code in your post has indeed syntax errors, but that is probably due to bad copy and pasting. Please post code that actually reproduces the problem.

Comment: Furthermore, there is JSON at all in your example.

Comment: @FelixKling i've removed the dangling } , just a bad copy and pasting , but how to put them so go can see them ?

Comment: Now that you removed the `}`, the code does still not exhibit the behavior you describe. I don't get a reference error: http://jsfiddle.net/y4Ptm/. We cannot help you if we cannot reproduce the problem!

Comment: @FelixKling i have something to add !! i forgot to write it . the two variables are in another function called recup() which take the variables from a form .. so now i see why the function go can't see them , but how can i do so the function go know the variables i have in the function recup ..

Comment: i must declare the variable as global .. but how can i do it , they are variables inside a function

Comment: Then please update your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You two errors, closing curly brace and plus character, the code shoud be:

```
var msg = "hello"; // i just simplified the value 
var name  = "test";

function go() {      // button send who call the function go

    var p_url="http://mysite.com/class?name=" + name + "&message=" + msg;

    $.getJSON(p_url, {

    }).done(function( data ) {
        $.each(data, function (key, field) {
           alert(field);
        });
    });  
    return false;
}
```

**UPDATE**: You need to make name and msg global:

```
var name, msg;

function recup() {
    var selectElmt = document.getElementById("name");
    var selectcat = document.getElementById("msg");

    name = selectElmt.options[selectElmt.selectedIndex].value;
    msg  = selectcat.options[selectcat.selectedIndex].value;
}


function go() {      // button send who call the function go

    var p_url="http://mysite.com/class?name=" + name + "&message=" + msg;
    $.getJSON(p_url, {

    }).done(function( data ) {

        $.each(data, function (key, field) {
           alert(field);
        });
    });  
    return false;
}
```

and `recup` need to be executed before `go`

Comment: i have something to add !! i forgot to write it . the two variables are in another function called recup() which take the variables from a form .. so now i see why the function go can't see them , but how can i do so the function go know the variables i have in the function recup ..

Comment: @neustre if they are in another function then you need to declare them outside of that function and don't use var when you assign them, so they will be global.

Answer (score 0):

> the two variables are in another function

Well, that explains it. A variable that is local to a function cannot be accessed by another function.

You have to define the variables in a scope that is shared by both functions. This could be the global scope, but you should avoid creating global variables (you cannot have a global variable with name `name` anyways, because it exists already).

If you want to assign a value to a variable in a higher scope, use `name = ...;` instead of `var name = ...;`.

Example:

```
(function() {
   // create a new scope so that we don't pollute the global scope

   // this variable can be accessed by both functions
   var answer; 

   function foo() {
       // don't use `var` here, otherwise you create a local variable which
       // shadows the variable with the same name in a higher scope
       answer = 42; 
   }

   function bar() {
       alert(answer);
   }

   foo();
   bar();
}());
```

Comment: @neustre: Thanks for that, that doesn't change anything for me answer though. It's exactly as I wrote.